# Deserialize BsonBinaryData using MongoDB c# driver

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, serialization, deserialization

I use the below extension method to serialize a List

```
public static BsonArray ToBsonDocumentArray(this IEnumerable list)
    {
        var array = new BsonArray();
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            array.Add(item.ToBson());
        }
        return array;
    }
```

All is well and  the list is written to MongoDb. Now, when i retrieve it, how to deserialize the BsonBinaryData stored in the DB to FieldToTypeMapping?

```
public static List<FieldToTypeMapping> ToFieldToTypeMappingList(this IEnumerable list)
    {
        var array = new List<FieldToTypeMapping>();
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            **var c = ?**
            array.Add(c);
        }
        return array;
    }
```